# Snap-to-Grid building palcement

Tags: unity

So I have created plane in which my buildings are going to be placed on and I was wondering how to add grids to it and make my building snap to it, just like in clash of clans.

Thanks!

Comment: I've fixed it for you. It's still an answer, even if the links are dead. Read it and ask follow up questions if you have trouble implementing it. Be specific about what you've done and what kind of troubles you're having.

Comment: @Byte56 could you please help me more?..I really want to know how to snap my buildings to the grid

Comment: You can email me and I'll let you know what my contract hire rates are.

Comment: @Byte56 what is your email?

Comment: Check my website.